# Leap Motion Top Down (Policy Flag) Processing

Tags: java, processing, gesture, leap-motion, virtual-reality

I have written an application in processing using Leap motion and everything works perfectly when testing on the desk with the leap the normal way up. The moment I try to use it top mounted (the intended usage scenario for product) it no longer detects gestures. Obviously if I flip my hands over it works fine but this is very counter intuitive and no good.

I am hoping that if I could set the policy flag to optimize HMD /Top down that this would resolve my issues, however I cannot figure out how I would go about doing this.

The Java implementation to set the policy flag is documented here: [Leap Motion Java Docs](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/skeletal/java/api/Leap.Controller.html#javaclasscom_1_1leapmotion_1_1leap_1_1_controller_1af8981a9ec355b85f3639b372fd80ea62)

If this is not possible does anyone have an suggestions to help when using top down tracking as scaleFactor() (a large part of what I am building) simply does not work and swipe gestures are very temperamental!

Any help is much appreciated. Will

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on how you tried to set the policy flag? Are you using the Leap Motion Java libraries directly, or are you using a wrapper library? Are you using the scale factor based on one handed (finger curl) motion or two-handed motion? If the hand is faced away from the sensors, finger curl might not have great fidelity to the user's motion since the software has to estimate the finger position based on very little information esp. the closer you get to a fist.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, I am using Leap Motion by Michael Heuer and since posting this question he has kindly updated the library to support optimisation of HMD via policy flag, however I am still having an issue. I can call the function to set the policy flag without error however it does not seem to have any effect. And when I check the active policy flags it still says default, whereas when I try to call others such as Background_frames it takes effect.

Comment: https://github.com/heuermh/leap-motion-processing/blob/master/examples/leap_hmd_policy_flag/leap_hmd_policy_flag.pde

Comment: There are currently some bugs in reading the policy flags (only the background policy flag changes the policy that you read back). The easiest way to tell if the HMD policy is set is to look at the Leap Motion "Software Log" from the Control Panel. You should see "Tracking optimized for head-mounted device." Also, it is currently not possible to set multiple policy flags at once in Java.

Comment: Ok brilliant, I will give that a test tomorrow! Ah ok, that is very useful to know (even if very irritating) seen as I was planning to use background_frames. I will report back here if it works!

Comment: The bug that prevented Java apps from setting more than one policy is fixed as of version 2.1.6 with the new setPolicy() function.